# Calculate point at distance between two coordinates

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Given two points `A` and `B` and a distance `d`, I'm trying to calculate a point `C` between `A` and `B` and at distance `d` from point `A`.

[image]

I was thinking on using Thales theoreme, but is there a better/simpler solution?

Cheers!

Comment: Compute the distance $\ell$ between $A$ and $B$, then the point will be $\frac{d}{\ell}B+\left(1-\frac{d}{\ell}\right)A$.

Comment: Intersection of the line $AB$ with the circle with its center at $A$ and the radius of $AC$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod And would that yield a valid (lat, lng) for point `C` ? :)

Comment: $C=\left(\frac{d}{\ell}\operatorname{latB}+\left(1-\frac{d}{\ell}\right)\operatorname{latA},\frac{d}{\ell}\operatorname{lngB}+\left(1-\frac{d}{\ell}\right)\operatorname{lngA}\right)$.

Comment: @conditionalMethod awesome! Is  in meters here?

Comment: The same units as $\ell$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can parametrize the line connecting $A$ and $B$ by

$$P(t)=A+t(B-A)$$

with $t\in \mathbb R$ such that

- $P(0)=A$
- $P(1)=B$

then indicating with

- $t_d=\frac d {|B-A|}$

we have that

$$C=P(t_d)=A+\frac d {|B-A|}(B-A)$$

that is in components

- $lat_C=lat_A+\frac d {|B-A|}(lat_B-lat_aA)$
- $lng_C=lng_A+\frac d {|B-A|}(lng_B-lng_aA)$

and

$$|B-A|=\sqrt{(lat_B-lat_A)^2+(lng_B-lng_A)^2}$$

Comment: Great! And how would I go about and convert that to valid lat, lng for `C`? ;)

Comment: @ThéoChampion You obtain the result component by component. I add that.